# Apache server can not find imports from the same directory of my main python app

Tags: python, apache, wsgi, python-module

It is a simple scenery: I am trying to use an Apache server to run a python app that imports another python file from its same directory. Could you help me with it, please?

Thus, I have a dash_app.py file trying to do

```
from db_reader import DBReader

DBReader.get_df_from_sqlserver_database(..., ..., ..., ...)
```

And in the same directory, I have the db_reader file with

```
class DBReader():
    def get_df_from_sqlserver_database(server_name, database_name, query, column_labels):
        ...
```

I am using the dash_app.py file likely as my WSGI file, configuring Apache doing

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName www.example.com
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptAlias / C:\Users\...\Documents\Projects\...\dash_app.py
    <Directory C:\Users\...\Documents\Projects\...\Python>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and when I try to run the web page via Apache server, Apache says that the module named db_reader can not be founded.